# How best to return HTML content from a PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have an application where I need to serve data back to a web page from a PHP file.

I can do this easily for images as I use the`<IMG>` tag with the `'src'` being the URL to the PHP page and then using `readfile()` to get the image to return.  It works a great.

However I am having an issues trying to return straight text with HTML tags embedded.

I can send the data OK, using:

```
header('Content-type: text/html');
ob_start();
echo $data;
ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();
```

$data contains a string of HTML, for example: "`We have 100's of <strong>GENUINE</strong> Men`"

but I am struggling to find the right HTML TAG to use in the first place, for example:

For images I use:

```
<img border="0" alt="" src="http://mydomain.com/test/index.php?element=2"></img>
```

at the moment for text I have used:

```
<object id="page" type="text/html" data="http://mydomain.com/test/index.php?element=1">
</object>
```

but the problem with the object is that although it receives the text in HTML format fine the `<object>` tag is not good to use as I have to set up a class for width etc.

I really need a way of the browser simply rendering what I send, with nothing else.

Comment: Maybe by MVC - Model-Viewer-Controller ? And you don't need to use ugly ob_* functions.

Comment: dude, sending image from php file is a bad practice!

Comment: keep appending the html tags to a variable. At the end of script, `echo` the variable

Answer (score 1):

Set your header before outputting, by default if no `Content-Type` header is specified, PHP will send it as `text/html`

Override it using:

```
// Headers are always set before any output
header("Content-Type:text/plain");

ob_start();
echo $data;
ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks fr your comments.

Comment: 1. Why is sending images bad practise?

2. The main issues is which HTML tag to use on the web page that is calling my PHP file.

3. I need it to be Content-Type: text/html but the real issue is what HTML tag to use on the web page calling my PHP script?

Comment: Please show your code, what do you output, what do you mean by `what HTML tag to use`, update your question to be more precise, No-one can help because we cannot understand what you are saying or what you want.

Comment: please include your php, what does `$data` output?

Comment: JustAnil: I have updated again. That is everything you need I think.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't know *why don't you use PHP itself to include your HTML to the original HTML file*, but how about an iframe?

```
<iframe src="./something/to/include.html?element=potassium"></iframe>
```

Or, if server supports it, you can use [SSI include](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes):

```
<!--#include file="./something/to/include.html?element=potassium" -->
```

Or, if you want to use jQuery (or you're using jQuery anyway), you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#whereToPutIt").load("./something/to/include.html?element=potassium"); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot do this as I am embedding my calls in to other peoples web pages.  My job is to return the data.  I have no control over the source HTML file other than they will call my server for data!  I hope this helps!

Comment: `I cannot do this` it's an iframe, js that writes the html or it simply won't work - take your pick =).

Comment: What I meant by I cannot do that is that all that happens is someone embeds the call to my PHP file within their web page.  My application returns HTML or Images.  Other than that I never have access to the web page that calls my PHP.

Comment: If all you can do is to provide the content (images or HTML source), then let others (those who want your content on their page) deal with the actual including (assuming they use PHP or ASP or whatever), since they apparently don't give you any other option.

Comment: Look at, for example, how almost all ad platforms work (they are almost all iframe+js based) - you are asking about the same sort of thing. There is no tag except an frames/iframe that allow rendering random content from a random source.

Comment: I have just been away fro two days so have just implemented the Javascript load(); approach and it works a treat.

Thanks to everyone that answered and thank you.

Comment: Hi, I will.  :-)

The only issue I have still is that someone can add up to 20 calls to my server so: ?element=1, element=2, etc...

So the Javascript solution is not elegant.  The iFrame solution likewise is not perfect as I just need to pass back data that the web page can process how it wants, <h1>, <p> etc etc...

Comment: That's so enough of a different question that is could deserve its own *thread* .. You should have stated all these parameters and conditions in the original question.

Comment: Ooops, sorry!

Yes, I need to be able to add up to 20 calls for data as mentioned above and just have the data inserted in to the web page as straight text/html